# Datadog: PostgreSQL custom_metrics returns a single row

Tags: postgresql, datadog

I wanted to create a graph in Datadog to display iddle connections per user.

Following this example: http://www.miketheman.net/tag/postgres/ I changed my postgres.yaml configuration to:

```
init_config:
instances:
- host: 127.0.0.1
  port: 5432
  username: datadog
  password: '**************'
  tags:
  - environment:qa
  - role:db
  custom_metrics:
    - # Postgres Connection state
      descriptors:
        - [datname, database]
        - [usename, user]
        - [state, state]
      metrics:
        COUNT(state): [postgresql.connection_state, GAUGE]
      query: >
        SELECT datname, usename, state, %s FROM pg_stat_activity
        GROUP BY datname, usename, state HAVING COUNT(state) > 0;
      relation: false
```

I can see the metric is appearing in Datadog, but I can just see one of the rows that should appear (has I have several databases in my PostgreSQL).

[Here is the datadog connection graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPsBL.png)
Am I missing any step? Is postgres.yaml missing any configuration?

Running that query in psql, I get this (modifying names but not data):

```
    postgres=# SELECT datname, usename, state, COUNT(state) FROM pg_stat_activity GROUP BY datname, usename, state HAVING COUNT(state) > 0;
           datname       |   usename   |        state        | count
    ---------------------+-------------+---------------------+-------
     compan_strawberr_qa | compan      | idle in transaction |     1
     compan_qa           | compan      | idle                |   130
     pineappplee_qa      | compan      | idle                |    10
     compan_strawberr_qa | compan      | idle                |    29
     compan_qa           | watermel    | active              |     1
     pineappplee_qa      | pineappplee | idle                |    10
     pear_qa             | pear        | idle                |     6
     postgres            | postgres    | active              |     1
     postgres            | datadog     | idle                |     1
     apple_qa            | apple_qa    | idle                |     1
     bblluebberrriiess   | compan      | idle                |     3
     compan_ser_qa       | ser_qa      | idle                |     4
     compan_service_qa   | compan      | idle                |    26
    (13 rows)
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution: the user `datadog` didnt have permission to read connections that wasnt form him. So it was just getting a single row.

I gave permissions for that user to read `pg_stat_activity`